# Download stopped working in jquery-1.9.1.min.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-web-api

I have a function in my javascript file for downloading an annotated canvas and then moving it to the server.The rest of the jquery is working fine .. but for some reason these particular functions have stopped working.

```
     $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnNext").click(function () {
        var canvas = paper.project.activeLayer.view.element;
        var img = $(canvas).parent().find('img')[0];

        //  var name = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Label9").text();
        var name = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField1").val();

        var mergeCanvas = $('<canvas>')
        .attr({
            width: $(img).width(),
            height: $(img).height()
        });

        var mergedContext = mergeCanvas[0].getContext('2d');
        mergedContext.clearRect(0, 0, $(img).width(), $(img).height());
        mergedContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        mergedContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
        //alert(canvas);

        self.downloadCanvas(mergeCanvas[0], name);
        //alert(mergeCanvas[0]);
        //alert(name);
    });

    this.downloadCanvas = function (canvas, filename) {

        /// create an "off-screen" anchor tag
        var lnk = document.createElement('a'), e;

        /// the key here is to set the download attribute of the a tag
        lnk.download = filename;


        /// convert canvas content to data-uri for link. When download
        /// attribute is set the content pointed to by link will be
        /// pushed as "download" in HTML5 capable browsers

        lnk.href = canvas.toDataURL();

        if (filename != "") {
            /// create a "fake" click-event to trigger the download
            if (document.createEvent) {

                e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
                e.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
                                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false,
                                 false, 0, null);

                lnk.dispatchEvent(e);

                // save image to server 

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'home.aspx/MoveImages',
                    data: '{ "imageData" : "' + filename + '" }',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (msg) {
                        //alert("Done, Picture Uploaded.");
                    }
                });
```

It was working perfectly a month back .. But it has stopped working and I am not able to figure out what could have changed?

the following scripts are used :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery- 
 1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

webmethod :

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void MoveImages(string imageData)
    {
        string fileName = "";
        // get computer name

        string clientMachineName;
        clientMachineName = Dns.GetHostName();
        string computerName = clientMachineName.Split('-').First();

        // get download location

        string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        string sourcePath = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Downloads");







        string pathstring = @"D:\........";


        string class = HttpContext.Current.Session["class"].ToString().Trim();
        string sub = HttpContext.Current.Session["subject"].ToString().Trim();
        string targetPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathstring, class);
        string pathstring1 = targetPath;
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathstring1, sub);





        // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.



        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {

            string[] jpg = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.jpg");
            string[] png = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.png");
            string[] files = jpg.Concat(png).ToArray();

            // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                if (s.Length > 0)
                {
                    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                    sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
                    //destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                    destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destFile, fileName);
                    if (File.Exists(destFile))
                    {
                        File.Delete(sourceFile);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.IO.File.Move(s, destFile);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Background.js :

```
'use strict';

let disableShelf = () => chrome.downloads.setShelfEnabled(false);
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(disableShelf);
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener

(disableShelf);
```

Comment: So you are using two versions of jquery in same page, that seems like a problem unless you did this `<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>`

Comment: If you have to use both of them, try the migrate js.

Comment: No i dont have <script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script> but howcome it worked fine before?

Comment: i tried this but it still does'nt work.

Comment: what is in `'home.aspx/MoveImages'` webmethod. can you post here.

Comment: I have added that in the question ..kindly check

Comment: @Sankar ..did u figure out what is the issue? I need to get this fixed and would appreciate any help. the ajax part seems to be not hiting the request.

Comment: Nothing looks *wrong* exactly. What errors do you see in Console? How would we replicate the issue so that we can assist?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined
    at background.js:4 . I get this error . have added the code for same in the question above